# why git pull need to commit a merger?

Tags: linux, git

I am learning git now.I have create a git repo in my linux use this command:

```
git clone --bare dev dev.git
```

And

```
cp -r dev.git /git/dev.git
```

Now i use another computer clone it

```
git clone ssh://xxx@xxx.com/git/dev.git
```

and push some commit.

I need my working dir in my linux server so i remove the first dev dir, and clone one new:

```
rm dev -rf
git clone /git/dev.git
```

But when i use git pull,i got this:

```
# Merge branch 'master' of /git/dev

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
```

what does it mean?

Comment: I always fetch without merging (`git remote update`) then look at what'd come down and decide whether to merge, rebase, or something else

Answer (score 1):

If `git pull` prompts you for a merge commit message, that means that your local branch and the upstream branch you are pulling from have diverged (meaning each branch has one or more commits the other does not have).

In that case, `git pull` will by default try to merge the changes. In your case, git has already performed the merge, and is asking you for a suitable commit message.

For more details, I recommend you read some introduction to git. A good text to read is the book "Pro Git", which is [available online](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). [Chapter 2.5](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) explains what happens during `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git pull --rebase
```

instead, or configure this as the default by using

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Alternatively, (my preference) do it in a 2-step process so you can see what will happen.

```
git fetch origin
git log ...
git rebase orign/my_branch
```

Disclaimer: Rebase rewrites history, but if you have not pushed any of the commits that will be rewritten, or if no one else is working on the branch that you are pushing then there is no real problem.